# The new Chrome browser app on iOS can't login to chat

Tags: support, chat, google-chrome, ios

The new Chrome browser app on iOS can't login to chat.

Am I the only one seeing this? All the globalauth checks pass.

Comment: It works for a friend of mine on his iPad. What problem are you having?

Comment: There is a Chrome browser app now? *Cool*. Off to test....

Comment: ... seems to work for me. What happens when you try, where are you being redirected?

Comment: No issues here either, iPhone or iPad (Chrome on iPad is *pretty*).

Comment: I was having a bit of trouble at first logging in to chat, but then again I was having the same troubles logging in anywhere. (My ISP has gone haywire, so this is probably a bug on my end).

Comment: Does the login via stackexchange.com work? Btw, global auth login works fine in Chrome on Android for me (but the standard Android browser is still better).

Comment: Does http://meta.stackoverflow.com/network-login-help give any clue? (Or is that what you're referring to with "the globalauth checks pass"?)

Comment: [status-norepro] on my iphone

Comment: Sorry for going AFK, a bit of an evening last night and I'm just now back. I'll try and ping balpha in the next few days in chat and test it live with him beside me.